# AlertView with textbox, how to gather the data from entered textbox

Tags: swift

Would like to gather the data from a AlertView out from the textbox. What I've found in the www is this:

```
@IBAction func showAlertTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        //Create the AlertController
        let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add User", message: "Enter username", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        //Create and add the Cancel action
        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
            //Do some stuff
        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
        //Create and an option action
        let saveAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
            //Do some other stuff
        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(saveAction)
        //Add a text field
        actionSheetController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField -> Void in
            //TextField configuration
            textField.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        }

        //Present the AlertController
        self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Im not aware of the functionality of the AlertController, so I don't know where to bring the entred text to a e.g. simple variable?

Comment: Note you can make your code more concise by not defining the type and letting it be inferred i.e. `let saveAction = UIAlertAction(...`

Comment: Also since you are using the `.Alert` style and not the `.ActionSheet` style you may may want to rename your variable something other than `actionSheetController`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like UIAlertController has a [textFields](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAlertController/textFields) property and since you only have one text field you should be able to access it in the following way

```
let textField = actionSheetController.textFields?.first as UITextField
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the textfields string by assigning it to a local variable in the configuration handler.

```
    //Create a local variable
    var alertTextField:UITextField?

    //Create the AlertController
    let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add User", message: "Enter username", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    //Create and add the Cancel action
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
        //Do some stuff
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)

    //Create and add save action
    let saveAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        //Unwrap your local variable and access your textfield
        if let textField = alertTextField {
            println("\(textField.text)")
        }
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(saveAction)
    //Add a text field

    actionSheetController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField -> Void in
        //TextField configuration
        textField.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        //Assign your UIAlertController textField to your local variable
        alertTextField = textField

    }

    //Present the AlertController
    self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version:

```
//Create a local variable
    var alertTextField:UITextField?

    //Create the AlertController
    let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add User", message: "Enter username", preferredStyle: .alert)

    //Create and add the Cancel action
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action -> Void in
        //Do some stuff
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)

    //Create and add save action
    let saveAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { action -> Void in
        //Unwrap your local variable and access your textfield
        if let textField = alertTextField {
            print(textField.text!)
        }
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(saveAction)
    //Add a text field

    actionSheetController.addTextField { textField -> Void in
        //TextField configuration
        textField.textColor = UIColor.blue

        //Assign your UIAlertController textField to your local variable
        alertTextField = textField

    }

    //Present the AlertController
    self.present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```